# Validation error displayed on custom experience dialog incorrectly

Tags: validation

In an SXA site I have cloned link list with item, and added a link custom editor button to allow editing of the list item fields.  These fields have required validation.  But I find that when I add values to each of those fields in the experience editor dialog and click ok I get this error:

[image]

On each of the required fields I have set it:
[image]

If I click ok.  And then go in to edit the item again then it's all green.

My template looks like this:

[image]

Why is it ignoring the field values when validating?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on a Sitecore 8.2 Update 7 instance. It is a known issue in Sitecore and they provided me a Sitecore Patch.

The Sitecore patch number is **SC Patch 221650-1**. The patch contains a dll, which is the `Sitecore.Kernel.dll`. You just need to replace the one that you have in the patch.

You can contact the [Sitecore Support](https://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/) and provide them the details of the error and also you can tell them that the reference number of the issue is **221523**

Comment: Thanks - have contacted support so will see what they come back to me with.  I am using Sitecore 9.1 so if it was a platform issue I would have expected they include it in the core product by now :)